# How to install pcl on indigo?

Tags: pcl, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed the [pcl website](http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html) and finished

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpcl-all
```

But I dont know what to do next. Can I use catkin install it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255645/how-to-install-pcl-on-indigo?/) by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2017-02-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-26**:
It seems like you've installed PCL, so I don't really understand what your problem is. What are you trying to do that makes you think PCL isn't installed?

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-26**:
@ahendrix because I found [another question](http://answers.ros.org/question/201516/installing-pcl-for-ros-indigo/) that changes other stuff. So it makes me confused. Also, the answer of it contains a command more than what I have finished. But I dont really understand it...Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have the ROS apt sources in your path you should already have a version of PCL available via APT. As in that other question it's recommended to use the already available ones instead of the PPA. The PPA is potentially newer and incompatible with what's available in the main ROS repos.

After indigo we use the version of PCL which is upstreamed in debian.

But either way you have pcl installed already.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-27**:
It seems that the intall process I have done is the same as on ubuntu. If I work on PCL, is it meaning that Im still working on ubuntu and there is no relationship with ROS?